# REST API Companies House(UK) get document

Tags: rest

I need some help to fetch a document with Companies House api from his REST API. I don't now how where I get the `token_type` and the `access_token`.

Here is the api: https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/

Here is the problem: https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/document/docs/document/id/content/fetchDocument.html

Can anyone help me with this?.

p.s. I'm using python3.5 and requests module.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the bottom of this page [this page](https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/index/gettingStarted/apikey_authorisation.html). The `access_token` will be provided to you by Companies House, and the `token_type` is the type of token it is, again Companies House will provide this to you when you register with them.

In short, you can't access this system without a key (`access_token`) which Companies House will provide when you [register](https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/developer/applications).

Comment: Thanks for the fat answer. They provide me the api key, it's the same access_ token?

Comment: Yes you send `Authorization: Basic EXAMPLE_KEY` replacing the example_key with your key.

Comment: Response status

0 [Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/script/jquery-1.8.0.min.js :: .send :: line 2"  data: no]

Response body

Failure while contacting API. Some possible causes are connection problems or cross-origin resource sharing protection. Please check javascript domains registered against APIKey / OAuth2 registration.

Comment: All result, thanks for your help, i can't vote, sorry.

Comment: But you can click the grey arrow to accept this as the best answer, you'll get some rep as well ;)